# Regex - replace all odd numbered occurrences of a comma

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string formatted like this:

```
"name", "bob", "number", 16, "place", "somewhere"
```

And I want, instead, to have a string like this:

```
"name": "bob", "number": 16, "place": "somewhere"
```

Also, the test cases do have some examples of strings like this:

```
"name", "bob", "hello, world", true
```

That would need to be formatted like this:

```
"name" : "bob", "hello, world" : true
```

...with every odd comma being replaced by a colon **(so long as that comma falls outside of quotes)**, how on Earth would I do that via regex?

I've found the following regex via Google: `/(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/,':'` , which matches the first comma instance. How do I alternate every other one from there on out?

**Edit for more info:**

What I'm trying to do is take this string where each value is delineated by a comma and format it like a JS object using `.replace()`. So, in this case, "name", "number" and "place" represent key values. They're not fixed, this is simply an example.

Comment: Can you use a custom callback for the replacement?

Comment: @alex - Could you clarify what you mean by that in this context?

Comment: Are the "name", "number", "place"... entries from a fixed set?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Which language do you use and why not String operations?

Comment: I'm using Javascript, this will be inserted into a .replace() method.

Comment: @Freiheit - nope, those are simply example values. See my clarification above.

Comment: Do you ultimately want a JavaScript object?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, no actually. I just want something formatted exactly like a JS object.

Comment: @radicalsauce: I just updated my answer based on the requirements, would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with this Regular Expression that covers all matches together.

```
(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)(,)(.*?,|)(?=.*?(?:,|$))
```

Replacement is: `:$2`

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wG4jR8/1)

Comment: Passes spec. :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Regex:

```
,(.*?(?:,|$))
```

Replacement string:

```
:$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rW9rL6/2)

**Example:**

```
> '"name", "bob", "number", 16, "place", "somewhere" '.replace(/,(.*?(?:,|$))/g, ':$1');
'"name": "bob", "number": 16, "place": "somewhere" '
```

**Update:**

If the field names are comma seperated then you could try the below regex,

```
> '"name", "bob", "hello, world", true'.replace(/("(?:\S+?|\S+ \S+)"), ("[^"]*"|\S+)/g, '$1: $2');
'"name": "bob", "hello, world": true'
```

Comment: Hmm, actually this is really close but not quite. Is there a simple way to exclude commas that fall inside of quotes? So if one of the values as, say, "Hello, world", it wouldn't be counted?

Comment: sorry man, my comment about it needing to exclude comma wrapped in quotes wasn't very obvious.

Comment: @radicalsauce see my update and let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Your regex isn't based on odd numbers of occurrences. I already commented this on @Christophe answer. Yours fails at `"name", "bob", "hello, world", true, "name", "bob", "number", 16, , "test", "place", "somewhere"` too

Comment: @revo may i know the reason for adding two consecutive commas? Don't assume the input by yourself.

Comment: It's not my assumption. It's what OP wants. _Odd numbers of occurrences!!_

Comment: @revo please read the question again: key-value pairs like a js object, so no consecutive commas!

Answer (score 0):

substitude `([^,]+),([^,]+,)` to `\1:\2` apply it once, globally.

it has to be applied once. otherwise every but the last one , will becomes :.

Comment: It shouldn't replace commas between quotations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's an updated answer that (ab)uses [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
function formatString(input) {
    var arr = JSON.parse('[' + input + ']'),
        result = '',
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result += JSON.stringify(arr[i]);

        if (i !== arr.length - 1) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                result += ': ';
            } else {
                result += ', ';
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/w9eghqmy/1

Comment: @Christophe: You're correct, just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "(.*?)(?<=\")(\s*)\,(\s*)(\S+)"
```

Replace by
     "\1\2:\3\4"

This works for all cases.

Comment: Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str='"name", "bob", "hello, world", true';
str.replace(/("[^"]+"), ("[^"]+"|[^",]+)/g,"$1: $2");
```

The first part of the regex `"[^"]+"` captures the name under quotes: "name" or "hello, world".

The second part of the regex `("[^"]+"|[^",]+)` captures either a name under quotes or a string without quote or comma: "bob" or true.

Comment: The problem with your regex is, it really doesn't replace odd occurrences of commas. It fails in `"name", "bob", "hello, world", true, "name", "bob", "number", 16, , "test", "place", "somewhere"`

Comment: @revo, ok, but your example doesn't look like what the OP is asking.

Comment: I just followed OP rules to make that input.