# Replace every odd comma with colon - Regex

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that converts every odd comma to a colon in python.

For example

```
"[2, 0.2520474110789976, 8, 0.25215388264234934, 3, 0.3560689678084889, 1, 0.3573715347893714, 4, 0.5626369616327825, 5, 0.793617535995843]"
```

gets converted to

```
"[2: 0.2520474110789976, 8: 0.25215388264234934, 3: 0.3560689678084889, 1: 0.3573715347893714, 4: 0.5626369616327825, 5: 0.793617535995843]"
```

I did go through other questions on StackOverflow and found the below question. However, the JS version doesn't seem to work in Python.

[Regex - replace all odd numbered occurrences of a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439045/regex-replace-all-odd-numbered-occurrences-of-a-comma)

I did the following based on the link above

```
pattern = "(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)(,)(.*?,|)(?=.*?(?:,|$))"
stringa = re.sub(pattern,": ",flat_list_string)
```

and got an output

```
"2:  8:  3:  1:  4:  5:  0.793617535995843"
```

instead of the one mentioned earlier.

I'm pretty new to Regex, so haven't tried much myself. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Update1: Pasted my incorrect output

Comment: Do you have the input as a string or array? If it's an array, you don't need regex.

Comment: And how did the JS solution not work? What code did you use?

Comment: @Sweeper Question updated. I have a string. Had a list earlier, but converted it to string.

Comment: What should be the expected outcome, if there are odd number of entries present?

Comment: The output looks like a dictionary. Do you want a dictionary as output or a string?

Comment: @taurus05 I have mentioned the expected outcome in the question.

Comment: @Sweeper I need a string.

Comment: @user3508140, you have mentioned the case, when there are even number of elements in the list. What would happen if it is something like `[1,2,3]`? What should be the outcome here?

Comment: @user3508140 I am not sure, what you are trying to do by this, but it doesn't make any sense. There is no way by which you can store key value pairs in a list, unless its a dictonary within a list.

Comment: @taurus05 It looks like a dictionary, but it isn't. I have to store this list in a file and the required format of a column is as mentioned in the question. Also, there won't be odd number of elements in the list. It'll always be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just be using the regex incorrectly. First, you should use a raw string literal `r"..."` so that you don't have to escape the backslashes:

```
pattern = r"(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)(,)(.*?,|)(?=.*?(?:,|$))"
```

Next, you should change the replacement string to `r":\2"`, which means `:` followed by group 2. The regex matches every odd comma, and also all the characters after it until the next even comma. It puts all this into group 2. Replacing with just `:` will replace all those matched characters too.

```
stringa = re.sub(pattern, r":\2",flat_list_string)
```

The JS regex also handles commas in quotes that the OP of the other post doesn't want to consider, such as:

```
"hello, world", 1, "bye, world", 2
      ^.               ^
these should not be counted as commas
```

If you do want to count these commas, then you can use this regex:

```
,([^,]+(?:,|$))
```

And replace with `:\1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result with this simple regex

```
re.sub(r'(\b\d{1,2}),',r'\g<1>:',search_string)
```